# Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode

Tags: errors

The display pdf is ok but i receive the following error message :

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.
```

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm,cleveref}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{ \left\lvert#1\right\rvert} 
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert} 

\begin{document}

\begin{aligned}
\norm{xy}_{\mathbb{H}}^4 ={} &  \abs{z+w}^4 + 16(x_3 + y_3 - \frac{1}{2}Im(z\bar{w}))^2  \\
     & = \abs{ \abs{z+w}^2 + 4i(x_3 + y_3 - \frac{1}{2}Im(z\bar{w}))}^2}) \\
      & = \abs{ \abs{z}^2 + 4ix_3 + 2z\bar{w} + \abs{w}^2+ 4iy_3 }^2 \\
      & \leq (\abs{ \abs{z}^2 + 4ix_3} + 2\abs{\bar{z}}\abs{w} + \abs{ \abs{w}^2 +4iy_3})^2 \\ & = (\norm{x}_\mathbb{H}^2 + 2 \abs{\bar{z}}\abs{w} + \norm{y}_\mathbb{H}^2)^2 \\
      & \leq ( \norm{x}_\mathbb{H} + \norm{y}_\mathbb{H})^4. 
\end{aligned}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder you could get a `correct` pdf if you have that error. Enclose the `aligned` environment with `$...$` pair.

Comment: i can't see why the question is downvoted

Comment: @touhami: There were two downvotes some minutes ago, however, not by me...

Comment: i did enclosed with $ .. $ but now i receive :! Incomplete \ifodd; all text was ignored after line 25.

Comment: @blackjack: Yes, there are more errors inside ;-) The typesetting is quite messy, actually

Comment: you almost certainly want this in a display, not in-line text.  either change `aligned` (which is a "subsidiary" environment) ro `align*` or wrap the whole thing between `\[ ... \]`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` instead of `aligned` so you won't need to put everything inside math mode.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with `\begin{math}...\end{math}` wrapping and some improvements for typesetting.

The left `)` in the second line is wrong, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Imag}{Im}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lvert\lvert}{\rvert\rvert}

%\newcommand{\abs}[1]{ \left\lvert#1\right\rvert} 
%\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert} 

\begin{document}
\begin{math}
\begin{aligned}
  \norm{xy}_{\mathbb{H}}^{4}  &=  \abs{z+w}^4 + 16(x_{3} + y_{3} - \frac{1}{2} \Imag(z\bar{w}))^{2}  \\
  & = \abs{ \abs{z+w}^{2} + 4i(x_3 + y_3 - \frac{1}{2}\Imag(z\bar{w}))}^2) \\
    & = \abs{ \abs{z}^2 + 4ix_3 + 2z\bar{w} + \abs{w}^2+ 4iy_3 }^2 \\
    & \leq (\abs{ \abs{z}^2 + 4ix_3} + 2\abs{\bar{z}}\abs{w} + \abs{ \abs{w}^2 +4iy_3})^2 \\ & = (\norm{x}_\mathbb{H}^2 + 2 \abs{\bar{z}}\abs{w} + \norm{y}_\mathbb{H}^2)^2 \\
    & \leq ( \norm{x}_\mathbb{H} + \norm{y}_\mathbb{H})^4. 
\end{aligned}
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this will be in-line math, which is probably not what is wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Perhaps. I could do of course use `\[...\]`, but as long as there is no other information from the O.P. I will keep it this way, stating however, I would not use it this way too

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `{aligned}`You must enclose your formula in `\[...\]` like:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
y &= mx+c \\
z &= nw+d
\end{aligned}
\]
```

`\[...\]`is not required if you are using `{align}`

Comment: Please don't advise `$$...$$` -- that's outdated syntax

Answer (score 0):

> Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.

The error is self-explaining, `\begin{aligned}` should be used only in math mode. You need to know what is **math mode** first:

> LaTeX allows two writing modes for mathematical expressions: the *inline* math mode and *display* math mode:
>
> - *inline* math mode is used to write formulas that are part of a paragraph
> - *display* math mode is used to write expressions that are not part of a paragraph, and are therefore put on separate lines
>
> Inline math mode delimiters
>
> 1. `\(...\)`
> 2. `$...$`
> 3. `\begin{math}...\end{math}`
>
> Display math mode delimiters
>
> 1. `\[...\]`
> 2. `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}`
> 3. `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`

In a word, you need write `\begin{aligned}` inside one of these math mode delimiters.